# Template, How to locate text

Tags: texshop, thesis, macos

Hey guys I am trying to write my thesis using latex. In a folder, I have the main file which I got from a template, as well as my chapter files. When I print, the thesis outputs on the cover "This thesis is for graduate studies", I want it to say "for undergraduate". However, the main file which contains the name, school, date, eyc including that text does not show that text anywhere. Where do I even find it?
Code for MainFile:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{MUNThesis}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

%\newcommand{\cm}{cm$^{-1}$}
%\newcommand{\dgC}{$^\circ$C}
%\newcommand{\dg}{$^\circ$}

%THIS IS WHERE YOU ENTER THE TITLE OF YOUR THESIS
\title{Albedo Parametrization for Models of Intermediate Complexity}

%THIS IS WHERE YOU ENTER YOUR NAME
\author{Name}

%THIS IS WHERE YOU ENTER THE NAME OF YOUR DEGREE
\deg{Degree}

%THIS IS WHERE YOU ENTER THE NAME OF YOUR DEPARTMENT, SCHOOL, or FACULTY
\fac{Department}

%THIS IS WHERE YOU ENTER THE DATE YOU SUBMITTED YOUR THESIS OR DISSERTATION
\date{August 2020}

%THIS IS WHERE YOU ENTER THE YEAR OF GRADUATION 
\copyrightyear{2020}

\begin{document}
\muntitlepage

%set the hierarchical drilldown to 3
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%set pagination to Roman numerals and begin at page i
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}

%%-------------Abstract-----------------
\doublespacing
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
%include the abstract.tex file
\input{abstract}

%%-----------Acknowledgements---------------
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments} 
%include the acknowledgments.tex file
\input{acknowledgements}

%%-----------Table of Contents------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}

%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\listoffigures{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
%\listofAbbreviationsandSymbols{}
\input{abbreviations}

%change single space to double space
\doublespacing
%maintain Roman numerals on the previous page
\clearpage
%set pagination to Arabic
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\include{Introduction}
\include{literaturereview}
\include{Parametrization}
\include{Results}
\include{conclusions}
\include {references}
\appendix
\include{ApendixA}

\end{document}
```

After the name, the file prints:

> A Dissertation submitted to the School of Graduate Studies in partial >fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of

I hope this is something that is possible to change.

Comment: And how should we know? You are giving absolutely no useful information... No code. Not even the name of the class.

Comment: Maybe you can use grep on all the files and find where your text is

Comment: I have added the code and added some extra information. Sorry about that guys,

Comment: presumably MUNThesis is a university-specific latex class, surely it comes with documentation on the commands it provides for adjusting the front matter? otherwise asking on a general site how to modify unseen code is probably not going to work, you need to at least give a link to the class.

Comment: It did not come with documentation, only notes on the coded page. I was unable to find the source for the original template.

Comment: Is there a file called `MUNThesis.cls`?

Comment: There is one! I found the text. Thank you so much.